# jquery array of integers into list in html

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a simple task in jquery and html, but I'm not really getting anywhere.

I have an array of variable size whose content I'd like to present in a scrollable list.

The html code:

```
<div id="listcss">
    <li id = "list">
    </li>
</div>
```

and the coffeescript

```
$("#listcss").show()
$("#list").html(ids)
```

Where ids is the incoming array.

Now when I run my code, this is the output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeydB.png)

In this case, the array is 6 elements long, but in general this is a variable size x.

It's just displayed as one long chain of numbers. I would like to break it up, so I get a list with x entries under each other.

This must be possible rather easily, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the array as text at Question? Is each digit an individual number?

Comment: Hi, no each number has 10 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ids` is an array, you can use `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `"<br>"`

```
 $("#list").html(ids.join("<br>"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is excactly what I needed.